# Why is rpmbuild installing package?

Tags: linux-kernel, sh, rpm, rpmbuild

Is rpmbuild actually installing packages I'm building? I'm trying to build an rpm package of kernel module. It runs fine up until it gets to the `(%install)`. The error claims to not have permissions. It looks like it's trying to install the module. Is it safe to assume I'm doing this wrong, or my `SPEC` file is incorrect?

Output with Error:

```
[arozar@buildhost SPECS]$ rpmbuild -bb bypass.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.SbBJbR
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cd /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf bypass-9.0.6
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/arozar/rpmbuild/SOURCES/bypass-9.0.6.tar.gz
+ /bin/tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd bypass-9.0.6
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nsuldT
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ '[' /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/bypass-9.0.6-1.el6.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/bypass-9.0.6-1.el6.x86_64
++ dirname /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/bypass-9.0.6-1.el6.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/bypass-9.0.6-1.el6.x86_64
+ cd bypass-9.0.6
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ rm -rf /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/bypass-9.0.6-1.el6.x86_64
+ cd lib
+ make DESTDIR=/home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/bypass-9.0.6-1.el6.x86_64
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILD/bypass-9.0.6/lib modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILD/bypass-9.0.6/lib/bplib.o
  LD [M]  /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILD/bypass-9.0.6/lib/bypass.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILD/bypass-9.0.6/lib/bypass.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILD/bypass-9.0.6/lib/bypass.ko.unsigned
  NO SIGN [M] /home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILD/bypass-9.0.6/lib/bypass.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64'
+ '[' 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 '!=' 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 ']'
+ make install DESTDIR=/home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/bypass-9.0.6-1.el6.x86_64/lib/modules/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64/kernel/lib/bypass.ko
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/home/arozar/rpmbuild/BUILD/bypass-9.0.6/lib modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64'
# remove all old versions of the driver
find /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 -name bypass.ko -exec rm -f {} \; || true
find /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 -name bypass.ko.gz -exec rm -f {} \; || true
install -D -m 644 bypass.ko /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64/kernel/lib/bypass/bypass.ko
install: cannot create directory /lib/modules/2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64/kernel/lib/bypass: Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 1
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nsuldT (%install)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.nsuldT (%install)
```

Here is my `.rpmmacros`:

```
%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild
```

SPEC file:

```
%define build_kernel 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
%define current_kernel %(uname -r)
%define destdir /lib/modules/%{current_kernel}/kernel/lib
%define realname bypass
%define lib lib

Name:           %{realname}
Version:        9.0.6
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Silicom Bypass Kernel Level Library

Group:          Silicom Ltd.
License:        GPLv2+
URL:            http://www.silicom-usa.com
Source0:        http://www.silicom-usa.com/ProductDrivers.aspx/%{realname}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)

# BuildRequires:  
# Requires:       

%description
Silicom’s Quad Port Copper Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express Bypass server adapter is a PCI-Express X8 network interface card that contains four ports on a PCI-E adapter.
Silicom’s Quad Port Gigabit Ethernet Bypass server adapter supports Normal, Disconnect and Bypass modes.

%prep
%setup -q

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
cd %{lib}
make DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT

if [ "%{build_kernel}" != "%{current_kernel}" ]; then
echo "This RPM is for %{build_kernel} kernel version. Ensure that you are usining the right module/kernel combo"
exit 1
fi

make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{destdir}/bypass.ko

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT


%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
# %doc



# %changelog
```

Comment: That build process is not honoring `DESTDIR` during the `install` target. It is broken (or needs that specified some other way).

Comment: So would this be something in `rpmbuild`, or the `source` code I'm working with?

Comment: The code you are building. You need to find out how they expect you to install to a custom directory (assuming they, or their build system, support that). If they don't then you get to do it manually (or edit their makefiles).